# Fragment Memory Leak?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

[Repo](https://github.com/MikaalSky/HotMoney/)

I can't manage to figure out what's wrong with my app right now. I have a navigation drawer and a single fragment that opens when the app starts, and also when you tap on the button in the nav drawer. Something's constantly racking up memory though. Keep tapping on the "Balance" button in the drawer and that's when the memory spikes up.

Comment: post your code and also the log.

Comment: I posted my code in the form of the repo, and there is no log. It's just slowly accumulating memory and not releasing it.

Comment: Yeah, i checked, its accumulating memory and i think its not by the fragment. I tried with adding a tag to the loaded fragment. So when next time it will check for the visible fragment, if it is already loaded and visible it will not load again. And i see the memory accumulating even when new fragment not loaded. Let me check for more...

Comment: Might have something to do with the button code.

Comment: It's related to the fragment switch it appears.

Comment: are u able to fix this? I tried out fresh sample with navigation view, same occurs to me. Its not fragment. As you said its button code.